# find last modified date on a google fusion table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

looking for ways to find last modified date on a google fusion table lead me to this post:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/fusion-tables-users-group/NVEr2TVR88I/discussion

is there a way to find out if the data has changed before syncing it with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last modified date is not available through the Fusion Tables API.  However, you should be able to get the last modified date through the Drive API (each Fusion Tables is another file in Google Drive).

Use the drive.files.get method with the table id.  You can try it out with the API explorer:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.get

First click on the button in the top right saying "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0".  Then, put in the fusion table id for the "fileid" field, and click "Execute".  You should see all the metadata you want.  It will also show you the API call that you need to construct in your application.

Comment: thanks, but this is a public table that is not in my google drive, this is the table: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1epTUiUlv5NQK5x4sgdy1K47ACDTpHH60hbng1qw so i wanted to track if there are any updates to this?

Comment: All your tables are also in Google Drive. Also, since the table is public, you don't need to authenticate.  If you go to the API explorer link I gave you, copy in your table id into the fileid.

I've done it for you - you can just go to this link and click "Execute":

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.get?fileId=1epTUiUlv5NQK5x4sgdy1K47ACDTpHH60hbng1qw&_h=2&